# Synonym request for [flightradar24] -> [online-radar]

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I'm trying to [suggest a synonym](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/online-radar/synonyms) for [flightradar24](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flightradar24) -> [online-radar](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-radar), but I'm getting this error message:

> [image]

Since this cannot be suggested, but it *can* be added outright by a mod, Bret suggested that the community make a decision on it. Thoughts?

---

Here are two other questions on MSO with the same error message:

- [Version Specific Tag Validation on Tag Synonym Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121457/version-specific-tag-validation-on-tag-synonym-page)
- [Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157869/version-specific-synonyms-can-only-be-created-by-moderators)

Answer (score 5):

Well, considering that they aren't technically using **radar**, I don't particularly like this synonymn anyway.

Maybe a generic tag like [online-flight-tracking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-flight-tracking) or even just [flight-tracking](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-tracking) would be better (do we even need to specify "online"?)?

Comment: I like `flight-tracking`. I'm not sure we need a tag for flightradar24 at all, and if we do, it probably should not be a synonym with flight-tracking.

Comment: "Flight tracking" also encompasses when I go to the airport and look at the big ol' board of flights and see which ones are 5 minutes delayed, in addition to the much more aviation-y ADS-B tracking. Is this intentional?